# How do I change from PHP 7 to 8 when using Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, php

I am running macOS 12.

Homebrew reports that PHP version 8.1.12 is installed.

If I type `php -v` into terminal. It reports that PHP 7.4.33 is running.

How do I get version 8.1.12 to be the version that macOS Recognises?

Comment: what happens when you type `which php`??  this will tell you the path to the PHP executable that is in you $PATH

Answer (score 2):

## Context

The way that the command line shell knows what you mean when you type `php` is to lookin a number of defined directories in your computers hard drive, this is known as your `$PATH` or path.

Homebrew automatically installs software into a directory of it's own that isn't in the path, and then uses symlinks to make them available in the path.

## Step 1 - Unlink PHP 7

When you first installed PHP it would have been the earlier 7.x version you are 'stuck' with, this can be removed from the path using `brew unlink php@7.4.33`.

## Step 2 - Link PHP 8

Once this is complete you can then issue `brew link php@8.1.12`, according to the aricle I am referencing this might require a forced overwrite, for example: `brew link php@8.1.12 --force --overwrite`.

## Step 3 - Confirm version

You should now be able to close the console and reopen it, then enter `php -v` and it should now be the newer version.

Source: https://localheinz.com/articles/2020/05/05/switching-between-php-versions-when-using-homebrew/